# Ruby: add custom properties to built-in classes

Tags: ruby, properties, customization, monkeypatching

**Question:**
Using Ruby it is simple to add custom *methods* to existing classes, but how do you add custom *properties*? Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
myarray = Array.new();
myarray.concat([1,2,3]);
myarray._meta_ = Hash.new();      # obviously, this wont work
myarray._meta_['createdby'] = 'dreftymac';
myarray._meta_['lastupdate'] = '1993-12-12';

## desired result
puts myarray._meta_['createdby']; #=> 'dreftymac'
puts myarray.inspect()            #=> [1,2,3]
```

The goal is to construct the class definition in such a way that the stuff that does not work in the example above will work as expected.

**Update:** (clarify question) One aspect that was left out of the original question: it is also a goal to add "default values" that would ordinarily be set-up in the *initialize* method of the class.

**Update:** (why do this) Normally, it is very simple to just create a custom class that inherits from Array (or whatever built-in class you want to emulate). This question derives from some "testing-only" code and is not an attempt to ignore this generally acceptable approach.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't simply create a class that inherits from Array and adds the desired functionality?

Comment: That is the preferred way to do it, but this question relates to some experimental code for testing purposes only ... I will update the question.

Comment: even though you've already accepted my answer, I've added an explanation on how to set up a default value for the attribute that you add (per your question update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in Ruby, you do not have access to attributes (instance variables) outside of that instance.  You only have access to an instance's public methods.

You can use [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001681) to create a method for a class that acts as a property as you describe:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Array
irb(main):002:1>  attr_accessor :_meta_
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> 
irb(main):005:0* x = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):006:0> x._meta_ = Hash.new
=> {}
irb(main):007:0> x._meta_[:key] = 'value'
=> "value"
irb(main):008:0>
```

For a simple way to do a default initialization for an accessor, we'll need to basically [reimplement `attr_accessor` ourselves](http://www.raulparolari.com/Ruby2/attr_accessor):

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_default accessor, default_value
    define_method(accessor) do
      name = "@#{accessor}"
      instance_variable_set(name, default_value) unless instance_variable_defined?(name)
      instance_variable_get(name)
    end

    define_method("#{accessor}=") do |val|
      instance_variable_set("@#{accessor}", val)
    end
  end
end

class Array
    attr_accessor_with_default :_meta_, {}
end

x = [1,2,3]
x._meta_[:key] = 'value'
p x._meta_

y = [4,5,6]
y._meta_[:foo] = 'bar'
p y._meta_
```

But wait!  The output is incorrect:

```
{:key=>"value"}
{:foo=>"bar", :key=>"value"}
```

We've created a closure around the default value of a literal hash.

A better way might be to simply use a block:

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_default accessor, &default_value_block
    define_method(accessor) do
      name = "@#{accessor}"
      instance_variable_set(name, default_value_block.call) unless instance_variable_defined?(name)
      instance_variable_get(name)
    end

    define_method("#{accessor}=") do |val|
      instance_variable_set("@#{accessor}", val)
    end
  end
end

class Array
    attr_accessor_with_default :_meta_ do Hash.new end
end

x = [1,2,3]
x._meta_[:key] = 'value'
p x._meta_

y = [4,5,6]
y._meta_[:foo] = 'bar'
p y._meta_
```

Now the output is correct because `Hash.new` is called every time the default value is retrieved, as opposed to reusing the same literal hash every time.

```
{:key=>"value"}
{:foo=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks for the reply. One thing that was left out of the original edit of the question: how to initialize values that would ordinarily be set-up in the *initialize* method. This was the aspect that did not seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't a property just a getter and a setter?  If so, couldn't you just do:

```
class Array
  # Define the setter
  def _meta_=(value)
    @_meta_ = value
  end

  # Define the getter
  def _meta_
    @_meta_
  end
end
```

Then, you can do:

```
x = Array.new
x._meta_
# => nil

x._meta_ = {:name => 'Bob'}

x._meta_
# => {:name => 'Bob'}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks for the reply. One thing that was left out of the original edit of the question: how to initialize values that would ordinarily be set-up in the *initialize* method. This was the aspect that did not seem to be working for me.